# Pattern for checking Indian Mobile number without ISD code

Tags: regex

I want to use a regular expression for the pattern attribute in HTML. It is for checking if entered string is a valid Indian mobile number or not (without any state code or whatsoever).

I have used the following pattern:

```
Contact No<input type="text" size="20px" placeholder="Mobile Number (10 digit number)" pattern="[7-9]{1,1}[0-9]{9,9}" name="contactno" required>
```

It validates all mobile numbers. The issue arises when you enter landline numbers. Say you enter a bangalore number, which is e.g, 08067546754. It still validates this as it considers it to begin with 8 instead of 0. So state codes like 070,080 & 090 are considered valid.

Is there a more precise expression? 
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern used "[7-9]{1,1}[0-9]{9,9}" works as expected. It matches substring "8067546754" in the source string "08067546754" and this is perfectly valid behaviour.

Regex pattern from the example doesn't include start and end of the string, it needs to be changed to:

```
^[7-9]{1,1}[0-9]{9,9}$
```

also, if leading zero needs to be matched, character class [7-9] needs to be changed to something like this:

```
^[0789]{1,1}[0-9]{9,9}$
```